# Analytic continuation of Riemann Zeta function.

Tags: complex-analysis, analytic-number-theory, riemann-zeta

I am reading about zeta function from book by Ingham. In that book the following theorem is given. I am unable to understand what does he mean by finite part of plane in the statement.
[image]

Comment: Well, is that an odd way to put things or what?! I think Sanchez is correct...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

By finite part of the plane he probably means the complex plane itself. The infinite part is probably the point of infinity of the Riemann sphere, where the zeta function has an essential singularity.

Comment: But if you take any part of plane which extends infintely in any direction and take the stereo graphic projection on to sphere, it will contain infinity. so what do you mean by finite part is complex plane?

Comment: @PhaniRaj, sorry, I don't understand what you are saying.

Comment: you said infinity part probably means point of infinity of the Riemann sphere, but if you take the the prt of plane with real part >1, then also it has infinity.

Comment: @Phani Raj, no. Take part of the plane with real part > 1 for example, it doesn't contain the point of infinity because by definition it is a (yes, unbounded) subset of the complex plane, which has NO point of infinity. The point of infinity is an extra construct that only exists in the Riemann sphere.

Comment: then where does the real infinity maps onto Riemann sphere?

Comment: @Phani Raj, the Riemann sphere is not the projective plane. There is only one infinity, rather than infinity in each direction.